# Return the prioritized value of lookup, if mutiple lookup value available for return field

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've to track the style/item availability in store (Bin), for which i have small set of data for example. I have multiple warehouse in Virtual warehouse column, Style is a item code, Stage is different stage of inventory pipeline.

So here its possible that one item may be available in different stages, as their can be multiple shipment. so here the important is, if the stock is available in "Bin" stage then i do not need to see if its available anywhere or not.

I tried to solve this multiple way but haven't succedded yet.

lets say, if my wareouse 130211 has a style 111131450 in 4 different stage, but among all if its available in bin then in new column it should mark "Bin" in all the rows or else it says "Putaway"
(should check warehouse wise).

[image]

Comment: Start with `COUNTIFS()`

Comment: I have used countifs in locationwisestatus
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,B2,$A$2:A2,A2,$D$2:D2,D2)>1,0,1)
this helps me in pivot to see the total options available in different bucket, but that can be overlapped. I want something where it prioritized the stage for style which are in multple stage.

Comment: Something along the lines of `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,D:D,"Bin"),"Bin","Putaway")`?

Comment: I will try it now, also I think I can use sumifs =IF(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2,D:D,"Bin")>0,"Bin","Putaway")

Comment: I like your suggestion it is better than mine. because it doesn't required my locationwise status count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, a good case for `COUNTIFS()`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,D:D,"Bin"),"Bin","Putaway")
```